# how to change SpannableString content?

Tags: android, spannablestring

I'm using SpannableString in my app, I just wanted to change its content to prevent to declare new `SpannableString` because I want to change its content more and more again ...

this is my Code :

```
SpannableString span;
span = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.C1_1));
//DO STH WITH span 
span = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.Q1_1));
//DO STH DIFFERENT WITH span
```

how can I reference one `SpannableString` and just change its content?

Comment: SpannableString's text content is immutable by default which means you cannot change it.

Comment: @PriteshVadhiya there is no such a method !

Comment: did you read `SpannableString` documentation? it clearly says what to do when you want to change the content of `Spannable` object

Comment: @pskink thanks i got the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since SpannableString is immutable object the only way to “change” value is by creating a new object.

There is a mutable  SpannableStringBuilder class which might help you.  You can read the documentation [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html)